# Excel - compare three cells, if same then something, if not then something

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

```
=IF(F9=G9=B9; H9*C9;"Problem")
```

This is the formula I'm using, but it always results in "Problem", even when the three cells have same text in them.

I want to compare the cells, and if they are the same then multiply two cells.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [AND](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AND-function-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9)

```
=IF(AND(F9=G9,F9=B9),H9*C9,"Problem")
```

You may need to use `;` instead of `,` depending on the version of Excel

Comment: Did you mean: =IF(AND(F9=G9,F9=B9),H9*C9,"Problem")